# Realizability of abstract polytopes

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, polytopes, abstract-polytopes

What are the conditions that allow an abstract polytope to have a non-skew (but not necessarily convex) realization in Euclidean space?

Comment: What information are you given about the abstract polytope?

Comment: All of the information